# How to reduce drawcalls in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, batching

I'm a beginner developer in Unity 3D and I'm working on a mobile game (Android). Everything works fine when I test my game on the editor (150 FPS) and on my latest phone (One plus 5, 60 FPS), but when I try it on my old phone (LG optimus G5 with android 6.0) I have only 15 FPS.

I try to test an empty scene with only a 3D cube and I can reach 25 FPS. I used the profiler to inspect my game and I see that I have more than 1300 draw calls on my home scene (which I use about 40 differents sprites and 30 differents meshes). I try to put some materials in static batching, enabled GPU instancing, reduce most of the quality settings, but nothing solves my issue. I also tried to disabled every GameObjects of the scene (except the camera) but it doesn't increase FPS (or only 5 FPS).

Here's my profiler on the empty scene (on the LG G5)  :

[image]

I developped another game with only UI elements and it works fine on this mobile LG G5.

Do i make a mystake in settings ? Or is my phone just too old for my game ? (I try to download crossy road which was made with unity and it works really nice on my old phone..)

How can i improve the graphics performances ?

I'm using universal render pipeline and unity 2019.3.5f.

Thanks in advance ! And please apologize my english isn't perfect.

Comment: "40 differents sprites and 30 differents meshes" leads to 1300 draw calls?

Comment: Yes.. I use some sprites several times but there's only 40 differents sprites. I think i have a problem in my quality or player settings because i have only 30 FPS in an empty scene. I tried to remove URP but it doesn"t solve my issue.

Comment: I dont think you can get so many draw calls with 70 gameobjects. Can you post a screenshot of Profiler on the Graphics tab and opened Hierarchy windows?

Comment: You can turn on the *SRP Batcher* in the RenderPipeline settings or set *GPU Instancing* in any materials.  These should have some effect.

Comment: Which shaders do you use on those gameobjects? How many light sources do you have? And I also see scripts (blue) have peaks too. So what scripts do you use? Performance is a very deep subject and Android is very sensitive to performance. I had a lot of problems too. Keep all simple and use mobile shaders with unlit and no light source and shadows.